# IC Rated, pivoting recessed (pocket) light for shower

Tags: bathroom, recessed-lighting

Looking for an IC Rated, pivoting recessed (pocket) light for shower.

Does anyone know if such a thing exists?  I've been scouring Amazon for a few days now and haven't come across any promising hits.

We're remodeling our master bathroom and unfortunately the ceiling above the shower is vaulted which doesn't lend itself very well to effective recessed lighting of the shower itself.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will find much of a selection. The 2014 NEC section 410.10.D states the fixture would need to be 8' above the shower threshold. on top of this if you had the height the fixture must be listed for a wet location. With this tight of a restriction most MFG's wont make a specialty fixture because of limited sales.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply mount conventional wet location cans on the angled joists? Use wide angle floods or even non-reflector bulbs. While the angled mount will create an off-angle bright spot, the face diffusers will mitigate that, and you could use two or three lower wattage units to spread out the coverage.